# UTF-8 conversion not working with String#encode but Iconv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had this with Iconv:

```
git_log = Iconv.conv 'UTF-8', 'iso8859-1', git_log
```

Now I want to change it to use String#encode due to deprecation warnings, but I can't, doesn't work:

```
git_log = git_log.encode(Encoding::UTF_8, :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => '')
```

I used to use Iconv here, and it's still working:

https://github.com/gamersmafia/gamersmafia/blob/master/lib/formatting.rb#L244

But when I replace these line with String#encode method, first gsub raises a **"invalid byte sequence in UTF-8"** error.

Do you know why?

Comment: What is your error? In Ruby 1.9.3, your encode call works for me: `"Foo\U+FFC2\U+FFA3".encode(Encoding::UTF_8, :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => ''); => "Foo"`

Comment: I used to use Iconv here, and it's still working: https://github.com/gamersmafia/gamersmafia/blob/master/lib/formatting.rb#L244 But when I replace these line with String#encode method, first gsub raises a "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8" error (info added to question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your call to `String#encode` you don’t specify a source encoding. Ruby is using the strings current encoding as the source, which appears to be UTF-8, and according to [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-encode):

> Please note that conversion from an encoding `enc` to the same encoding `enc` is a no-op, i.e. the receiver is returned without any changes, and no exceptions are raised, even if there are invalid bytes.

In other words the call has no effect, and leaves the bytes in the string as they are, encoded as ISO-8859-1. The next call to `gsub` then tries to interpret these bytes as UTF-8, and since they are invalid (they are unchanged from ISO-8859-1) you get the error you see.

`String#encode` has a a form that accepts the source encoding as the second parameter, so you can explicitly specify it, similarly to what you are doing with Iconv. Try this:

```
git_log = git_log.encode(Encoding::UTF_8,
                         Encoding::ISO_8859_1,
                         :invalid => :replace,
                         :undef => :replace,
                         :replace => '')
```

You could also use the `!` form in this case, which has the same effect:

```
git_log.encode!(Encoding::UTF_8,
                Encoding::ISO_8859_1,
                :invalid => :replace,
                :undef => :replace,
                :replace => '')
```

Comment: Excelent, this works! I appreciate you also explained what was happening, instead of just putting a line of code :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach, which removes a character from a string if the character is mal-encoded:

```
invalid_character_indices = []
mystring.each_char.with_index do |char, i|
  invalid_character_indices << i unless char == char.encode(Encoding::UTF_8, Encoding::ISO_8859_1,:invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "")
end
invalid_character_indices.each do |i|
  mystring.delete!(mystring[i])
end
```